# How can i put my database result in 3 dimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my code

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,text,date FROM news limit 5");
```

is there any way to extract title,text,date from `$result` and put them into 3 dimensional array?

Comment: What do you want your three dimensional array to look llike?

Comment: To you meant two dimensional? Where the second dimension contains three values, like `array(array('title', 'text', 'date'), array('title', 'text', 'date'))` ?

Comment: an array of arrays will be a 3d array for you?

Comment: Then you have plenty of answers to pick from :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you're after is actually a two-dimensional array (in which the second dimension has three elements). (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

One of the comments under the documentation of [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) has an answer to this:

(Disclamer: This code is **unnecessarily verbose**. I prefer not changing it though as I have copied it from the above web-page. For improvements, I refer to the comments.)

```
<?php
function mysql_fetch_rowsarr($result, $numass=MYSQL_BOTH) {
  $i=0;
  $keys=array_keys(mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass));
  mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass)) {
      foreach ($keys as $speckey) {
        $got[$i][$speckey]=$row[$speckey];
      }
    $i++;
    }
  return $got;
}
?>
```

You should then be able to use this function as

```
<?
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,text,date FROM news limit 5");

$arr = mysql_fetch_rowsarr($result);
$row_2_title = $arr[2]['title'];
?>
```

Comment: Unnecessary complex. The foor loop is the same as `$got[$i]=$row;`

Comment: Ah, that's nicer, thanks. As I've cited a different page, I won't change the code though... I'll let your comment highlight the possible improvement :-)

Comment: No it is just complex code, not more functionality. Or maybe I don't see it. Please explain me why `$keys` is needed.

Comment: I've added a remark about your suggestions for improvements. I want to add though, that I'm one of those people that think down-votes should be reserved for *wrong* answers, that provide *incorrect* results.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,text,date FROM news limit 5");
$array = array();
$i = 0;

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) {
    $array[$i] = array();
    // i'm just guessing at what sort of array you want
    $array[$i][$row['title'] = array( 'text' => $row['text'], 'date' => $row['date'] );
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `]` and the `$i` counter is not needed, `$array[]` is just fine. And somehow the structure does not make much sense. You will create an array that contains arrays that contain an array with one element (which is an array). There is one array too much ;)

Comment: Yeah not sure why the OP wants a 3d array (i'm guessing just a mistake) But the reason the $i counter is needed is if you do this:

$array[] = array();
$arra[][$row['title'] = array( //stuff);

If you print_r that you'll have two elements in the array instead of one.

Comment: Then why not: `$array[] = array($row['title'] => array( //stuff));` or even better (yeah I know the OP says 3 dimensions, but your example just generates a complex structure): `$array[$row['title']] = array( //stuff));`

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know what the ... you need a three-dimensional array for but ok:

```
$dim = array();

$result = mysql_query(...);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
    // Whatever you want to save in that particular bucket,
    // I'll be using the result set
    $dim[$row['title']][$row['text']][$row['date']] = $row;
```

Strange, ...

Answer (score 0):

If we are already guessing, here is mine:

```
$results = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

which will create an array like this:

```
array(array('title' => 'foo',
            'text' => 'bar',
            'date' => 'baz'),
      //...
)
```